# M3U8 hangs after a few seconds

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming

I have a small experimental clip below :

http://d3fnzeq4kk32oq.cloudfront.net/802/test_1.m3u8

The problem I am facing is that after a few seconds, the video hangs.

I would appreciate if someone is able to help me

1. Identify the issue
2. Any fix
3. Any tool for detecting or fixing it

Comment: Your link points to a 368 byte file, and it does not play in VLC.

Answer (score 2):

I so no issues. This m3u8 is pointing to the last couple seconds of what was a live broadcast.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:54675
#EXTINF:10.0,
http://d3fnzeq4kk32oq.cloudfront.net/802/chunk-20131128_0122_54675.ts
#EXTINF:2.188,
http://d3fnzeq4kk32oq.cloudfront.net/802/chunk-20131128_0123_54676.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
http://d3fnzeq4kk32oq.cloudfront.net/802/chunk-20131128_0123_54677.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

HLS splits the video into segmeents. This playlist starts on segment number 54675 and ends on 54677. `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` tells the player to stop playing, as we are out of segments.

While this stream was live the m3u8 would have been updating.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-12

Comment: How to figure out if the m3u9 was pointing to a live broadcast like you have mentioned ?

Answer (score 2):

The `.m3u8` file is not a *video clip*; it is a *manifest-type* file that is used in HTTP video streaming. It specifies the URL of `MPEG2-TS` encoded video segments that are usually about 10 minutes in length.

1. The server sends this `.m3u8` file to the client
2. Then the client extracts the URL to the `.ts` video segment and then displays the video segment.

Under normal live streaming conditions, a new `.m3u8` file is sent from the server to the client every 10-minutes so it will know the URL of the next 10-minute video segment.  When there are no more segments, or the live streaming event has terminated, the server sends a `.m3u8` file with the `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` directive, which tells the client that there will be no further segments, as szatmary explained above.

Thus, your video "hangs" as you described as there are no more segments available.

**To Fix**:

There is no fix needed, because the server has not provided any more segments.

**Resources**:

The best tool for detecting this is an editor like *vi* (vim) which will let you see the directives in the `.m3u8` file so you can check for the `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` directive. Or just use `cat` or `tail` to show the contents of the `.m3u8` file.

The link to the IETF draft on HTTP Live Streaming that szatmary gave is very informative and explains all of the directives that are used in the `.m3u8` file.

Since Apple developed and defined this protocol, this is the best source for info:
https://developer.apple.com/streaming/

Additional resources can be found here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

Comment: "are usually about 10 minutes in length" .. I think you meant seconds? #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10 - refers to a 10 second clip length